# I'm replacing a 24VAC transformer that supplies power to a motorized skylight

Tags: voltage

I could use some help selecting a replacement transformer with the correct amps. The transformer supplies power to a PCB that switches a small low-speed hi-torque motor via a battery operated remote control to lift and shut the skylight. The skylight weighs about 40 lbs max.

The local electronic supply store couldn't identify the transformer and couldn't give me any more info.

After much googling and multiple calls to the manufacturer, the only information I have been able to find about the motor and transformer are as follows:

Transformer: 120VAC in, 24VAC out, Class 2.
Motor: 60W, 60Hz.

Without knowing the exact load requirement of the motor, do you foresee any problem using a 40VA 24VAC transformer with say 2.5 amps?

Thanks.

Comment: With a 60W motor, and a 40W transformer (VA is volts times amps, or watts), the transformer doesn't seem like a good choice.

Comment: The motor is not running 24/7 so you might get away with it .Be sure to use a thermaly protected transformer to avoid house fires.

Answer (score 2):

24V AC out at 60 watts implies a current of 2.5 amps.

A 40VA transformer at 24V AC implies a full load current of 1.67 amps.

Those are the facts and I'll leave it for you to decide but here's a clue - only one is probably suitable.